# Websites not playing certain videos, loading certain icons, and format is messed up

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1

I use Firefox and randomly it has started messing up. I tried reinstalling it but nothing happened. Example, I will go to MSN and click a video and sometimes it starts and sometimes it just tries to load and nothing happens. Another example, I went to Amazon two hours ago and it worked fine.

Now when I go the format messed up with sentences overlapping and no pictures. I reload it and the format is fine but no pictures. Basically every time I refresh a website it is a new messed up layout.

Comment: Latest updates? JavaScript and Flash etc. are enabled?

Comment: Do you have Flash Player installed? maybe some sites still use Flash

Comment: Everything is updated. I have Java and Adobe Flash Player. I am not a computer person but I assume they are enabled because up until a few days ago everything worked.

Comment: What antivirus are you using?

Comment: McAfee is what I have installed.

Comment: Firefox 39, right?

Comment: How is your internet connection? I have seen this kind of problem when the ISP is having capacity problems and the connection times out before the page is loaded. It is more technical, but you can select "Developer" in the menu and click on "Network". Reload the page and you can see what is loading or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be having DNS issues if reinstalling didn't fix it. This would explain why only some assets are loading on pages and external assets do not. I've had a very similar issue myself recently which is definitely down to DNS.

Do other devices on the network have a similar issue?

if so, I'd be inclined to reset your router to factory default and re-configure the ISP user/password settings only, nothing more.